# Need to trigger a Linux Backend script with WordPress Button

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, git, shell

I have made a button on wordpress and linked it to a linux backend script. 
This gives me no error, and the default user output is "www-data"

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
touch file
```

But I want to **trigger a git commit using my local user through this script.**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u my_username -p my_password -H sh -c "cd /var/www/html/forcetalks_new/; /usr/bin/git add .  ; touch test_file"
```

This is **neither touching the file not adding the files.** I wonder what could be the possible reason. And any other solution is welcomed.

PS. I tried using GIT commands in the first script after giving GIT sudo permissions to "www-data" and that didnt work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the first script approach with:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u my_username -p my_password -H sh -c "/path/to/script > /path/to/log 2>&1"
```

So a script calling a script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
whoami
git status
git add .
touch file
```

The goal is to *see* what is going on with `/path/to/log`, thanks to the `bash -x` option (and the `git status` command)

Note that if you want to add "`file`" itself, you should touch the file first, then add.
Note also that a `git commit` might be needed at some point to actually persist those changes in the Git repository